# Mock service worker is unable to intercept network request

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, msw, react-testing

I have a react project in this [git repo](https://github.com/tganesh07/reactJs-testing) created from scratch without using create-react-app, so I am using jest.config.js and jest.setup.js files as suggested by [msw doc](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node#using-manual-setup) for mocking network request for testing. I get the below error when I executing the test.

> (node:12207) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
> console.error
> Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

The same test code works fine when I create a new project using create-react-app containing setupTests.js, but I want to mock api request in a react project which was created manually from scratch.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

In the tutorial for `msw`, the mock server is configured in `setupTests.js`.
Because CRA (create-react-app) already configure `jest` for you and CRA will load `setupTests.js` when you run test with `react-scripts test`.

If you want to create a new project from scratch (supposed you already installed react, react-dom, ... ).

You have to config `jest` your self  (refer this [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react#setup-without-create-react-app)), steps needed:

1. Change `test` scripts in `package.json` to `jest`
2. Install dependencies (babel, preset for jest, etc)
3. Config jest with `jest.config.js` (like you did, i also add jsdom as test environment)
4. Setup `jest.setup.js` to load mock server

I created a [PR](https://github.com/tganesh07/reactJs-testing/pull/1) that did above steps for you, to test just run

```sh
npm run test App.test.js
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped me in the sample project. let me replicate the same changes in another real time project.